# Can't login to Magento Connect Manager - 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've been banging my head against my keyboard with this problem! A couple days ago it worked just fine, however now I cannot login to my Magento Connect Manager. It redirects me to the 404 page of my root folder (magento is in a subfolder).

**A little bit about my setup...**

I have magento installed in a subfolder (public_html/magento)

I have Opencart installed in my root folder (that is currently my live site I am testing magento in the subfolder and preparing to launch soon).

When I try to login to Magento Connect it redirects me to the 404 page of my opencart site in my root folder.

**Some things I have ALREADY tried...**

Changing permissions of "downloader" folder and it's index.php to 0777, 0755, 0644, etc. Multiple combinations.

Re-installing magento

Double checked base_url rewrites in my backend config (as well as in the database)

Changing my admin password

Deleting the last extension I had installed before I noticed it stopped working

Used a Magento clean-up tool

I'm hoping someone can help me! I have gone through everything I can find on google and unfortunately nothing is working. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try  `/yourWebSite/index.php/admin`

Next:If you have enabled System Log in Magento then you can see the log. It is present in var/log/system.log.

Also look to the the app/etc/ directory under your Magento installation and open the local.xml, 
look to `<frontName>` node.

Clear Cache.

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache, as well as re-indexing everything. I looked at the local.xml file and this is what it is: <frontname><![CDATA[admin]]></frontname>

I also downloaded the system.log and the only thing coming up is "ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /home/MYUSER/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Observer.php on line 166" - do you think this would have anything to do with it?

Comment: If you get the above error in system.log, then you have to visit these 2 links http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/217491/ and http://support.atandra.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/92/4/magento-array_key_exists-error. I think these may solve your problem

Comment: I tried the "property_exists()" function and that didn't work. I got the error to go away with using the "if (is_array($loginParams))", however I still am not able to login to the Connect Manager :(

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the Magento Cleanup tool.  I know you said you played with the permissions, but if you didn't tweak anything that caused this, its hard to say.  Its worth a try.

Download Magento Cleanup Tool (http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/_media/groups/227/magento-cleanup2.zip)
Unzip magento-cleanup.php to the root directory where Magento is installed.
Browse to http://yourdomain.com/magento/magento-cleanup.php

Answer (score 0):

I've get this problem too. After some debug job I've found it is a timeout problem indeed.
There were too many xml files in directory /var/packages.
Magento stores every package's xml have ever been installed via Connect Manager.
So you can delete or rename xml files have a newer one also.